# error in Search SQL query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a search function that searches a GridView for a certain value then returns that row. I tested this query in MySQL workbench and it works but when the query is run in visual studio I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '?parameter0' at line 23

```
      StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(SearchSQL);
                if (SearchFieldKey != null && SearchFieldKey.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (SearchTerms != null)
                    {
                        SQL.Append(" HAVING ");
                        for (int i = 0; i < SearchFieldKey.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (SearchFields.ContainsKey(SearchFieldKey[i]))
                            {

                                SQL.Append(SearchFields[SearchFieldKey[i]] + " LIKE ?parameter" + i.ToString());
                                param.Add(new MySqlParameter("parameter" + i.ToString(), "%" + SearchTerms[i] + "%"));

                                if (i != SearchFieldKey.Length - 1)
                                    SQL.Append(" OR ");
                            }
                            else
                                throw new Exception("Error: Attempted to search on invalid field. Check SearchFields Argument.");
                        }
                    }
                }

 SQL.Append(" '); ");
 SQL.Append ("prepare stmt from @sql; execute stmt; deallocate prepare stmt;");
```

When debugging this I copied the exact query being run and pasted it into Workbench and it works. So I don't know why it won't run in visual studios.

The query gets run from this code:

```
 DataTable dtJobs = Job.CustomFill(SQL.ToString(), param);
```

And the parameters passed in are "%TESTING%"

The query that displays the rows from the database:

```
private static string SearchSQL
    {
        get
        {
            return @" 
                                                            SET group_concat_max_len=10000000;
                                                            set @sql = null;
                                                                select
                                                                  group_concat(distinct
                                                                    concat(
                                                                       'MAX(CASE WHEN pt.Code = ''', 
                                                                        pt.Code ,
                                                                        ''' THEN jp.AdvisedQty ELSE 0 END) AS `',
                                                                        pt.Code, '`'
                                                                    )
                                                                  ) into @sql
                                                                 FROM customer c
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
                                                        JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = 'Debtor'
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
                                                        LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
                                                    WHERE c.Company_ID = ?compid;

                                        set @sql = concat('select 
                                                            c.Name,
                                                            COUNT(distinct jn.ID) as Jobs,
                                                            (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =3 AND JobID = jn.ID) as CollectName,
                                                            (SELECT Name FROM job_address WHERE AddressType =2 AND JobID = jn.ID) as DeliverName,
                                                            ', @sql, ' 
                                                        FROM customer c
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_address ja ON c.AccountCode = ja.Code AND c.Company_ID = ja.Company_ID
                                                        JOIN  AddressType jat ON ja.AddressType = jat.ID and jat.Description = ''Debtor''
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON ja.JobID = jn.ID
                                                        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON ja.JobID = jp.ID
                                                        LEFT JOIN piecestype pt on jp.TypeID = pt.ID
                                                   WHERE c.Company_ID = ', ?compid,
                                                    ' GROUP BY c.ID


                                                                            ";
        }
    }
```

So my search query puts the `HAVING c.Name LIKE "%PRL%" ');` just after the GROUP BY from the query. Then the Append statements put the prepared stmts at the end of the query.

Comment: I think you need to use '@' instead of '?' when binding parameters.

Comment: Add code to print out the completed SQL so you can see it. It should be obvious from that what the problem is. If, for some reason, it's not obvious to you, edit the completed SQL into the question, and it likely will be obvious to somewhere here. At first glance, though, you're missing the logical `AND` or `OR` operators between parameters.

Comment: @EvanMulawski MySql can use `?`

Comment: Does the parameter come in with the percentage signs already? If so, you don't need to add them again here: param.Add(new MySqlParameter("parameter" + i.ToString(), "%" + SearchTerms[i] + "%"));

Comment: @KoBE no it doesn't come in the percentage signs already

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I put the query being returned into my question

Comment: @EvanMulawski changing to `@` didn't solve it

Comment: @user123456789: Yep, @Joel was correct - MySQL for .NET can use either `@` or `?`.

Comment: Really that works in workbench?  You have name in the select and ID in the group by.

Comment: @Blam this query does display all rows without the having statement so yes it does work. I'm just having a problem after that line is added

Comment: @Blam Mysql doesn't follow the standard very well for group by rules, either. Really, anyone who still has a choice these days should go for Postgresql instead of MySql. MySql is just awful about standards compliance in so many ways. It's the Internet Explorer of server databases.

Comment: @Blam I edited my question again to show the whole query that is being run

Comment: @EvanMulawski I edited my question again to show the whole query that is being run

Comment: First you say it works without a having and now you post the real query and it does not even have a "having".    And the query is clear off the the right.  Show some effort.

Comment: @Blam the new query I uploaded is not the query that is returned. That is the query that is run from `StringBuilder SQL = new StringBuilder(SearchSQL);` The SearchSQL function does work without having. It is when having is added to the query that something is wrong

Comment: The answer is only as good as the question and right now.   Voting to close.  So the having breaks it and yet you have "having" anywhere in the question.  No way this syntax is working WHERE c.Company_ID = ', ?compid,' GROUP BY c.ID

Answer (score 0):

Based on the SQL you posted, the problem is the double quotes:

```
HAVING c.Name LIKE "%PRL%"
```

The SQL standard says the double quotes are used for identifier names, like aliases, columns, tables, schemas, procedures, views, or databases. If you want string literals, you need to use single quotes here:

```
HAVING c.Name LIKE '%PRL%'
```

This is one of those many places that MySql does a poor job of following the standard (depends on how you have `ANSI_QUOTES` set), but if you want to be sure, try for single quotes.

Comment: no putting single quotes doesn't solve it `param.Add(new MySqlParameter("parameter" + i.ToString(), '%' + SearchTerms[i] + '%'));`

Comment: That's not where the single quotes go. I suspect the problem is in your CustomFill() method.

Comment: then where should the single quotes go?

Comment: I posted the query that the CustomFill() method returns. I don't see the problem with it

Comment: The problem with it is that with the wrong ansi_quotes setting it's not valid sql. You need to get it to generate the string literal with single quotes. Even worse, the fact that you see values substituted into the query at all is a **HUGE** red flag that it's not handling the parameters correctly and potentially leaving your app wide open to sql injection attacks.

Comment: Also, the error mentions `parameter0`, which is not included with the SQL code. So the code you posted does not match the code sent to the server. I just want to see the final result of SQL.ToString(), parameter placeholders and all.

Comment: when I debug and get the query from CustomFill() the query is `HAVING c.Name LIKE ?parameter0` then I look in param to get the value which is `"'%ALLTRANS%'"`

Comment: ok I edited the code in my question. The query returned is what comes from SQL.ToString(). Then the parameters for compid and parameter0 comes from param in CustomFill()

Comment: I edited my question again to show the whole query that is being run